# Sentry-elixir cannot encode tuples

Tags: tuples, elixir, sentry

I get it that in a pure sense, JSON doesn't account for tuples, but I don't think it's unreasonable to treat tuples as lists in terms of the JSON encoding. \Has anyone else faced and resolved this? I'd like to stay out of the business of pre-processing my error data to replace tuples with lists.

Perhaps I need to specify a different serialization approach?

EDIT: here is a practical example:

Here is some toy code.

```elixir
the_data = {:ok, %{...}}
Sentry.capture_message(message, the_data)
```

All it does is attempt to send a message to Sentry with tuples in the data.

If you're unfamiliar with Sentry, the sentry-elixir library provides two functions (among many other, of course) that are used to explicitly send either exceptions or messages to Sentry. The functions are:

```elixir
Sentry.capture_exception/2
Sentry.capture_message/2
```

In addition, errors are sent to Sentry when they bubble up to the "top". These can't be intercepted so I have to specify (and implement) a `before_send_event` "handler" in the configuration for Sentry.

This is what my configuration looks like for the environment I'm working in:

```elixir
config :sentry,
  dsn: "https://my_neato_sentry_key@sentry.io/33333343",
  environment_name: :staging,
  enable_source_code_context: true,
  root_source_code_path: File.cwd!(),
  tags: %{
    env: "staging"
  },
  before_send_event: {SomeApplication.Utils.SentryLogger, :before_send},
  included_environments: [:staging],
  filter: SomeApplication.SentryEventFilter
```

My `before_send` function basically attempts to sanity check the data and replace all tuples with lists. I haven't implemented this entirely yet though and instead of replacing all tuples I am temporarily using `Kernel.inspect/2` to convert it to a string. This isn't ideal of course, because they I can't manipulate the data in the Sentry views:

```elixir
  def before_send(sentry_event) do
    IO.puts "------- BEFORE SEND TWO ---------------------------"
    sentry_event
    |> inspect(limit: :infinity)
  end
```

This results in the following output:

```elixir
{:invalid, {:ok, the_data}}
```

And the capture_message fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `sentry` uses `jason` to encode its JSONs and, again by default, `jason` doesn't encode tuples. You can change that by implementing `Jason.Encoder` for `Tuple`:

```elixir
defimpl Jason.Encoder, for: Tuple do
  def encode(tuple, opts) do
    Jason.Encode.list(Tuple.to_list(tuple), opts)
  end
end
```

Be warned - this will have a global effect on how tuples are converted to JSON in your application.